# How to wait for an open port with netcat?

Tags: bash, shell, netcat

I'm trying to do a custom dockerfile with jenkins on it. I would to wait until port 8080 is open instead of doing an ugly 'sleep 60' with netcat but I'm not very confident with bash scripts and netcat.

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
opened=0
 
while [ "$opened"  == "0" ]; do
  echo "Waiting jenkins to launch on 8080..."
  nc -vz localhost 8080
done
 
echo "Jenkins launched"
```

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can't set netcat to wait until some port is open, so you have to add part for waiting before next check is made. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Waiting jenkins to launch on 8080..."

while ! nc -z localhost 8080; do   
  sleep 0.1 # wait for 1/10 of the second before check again
done

echo "Jenkins launched"
```

Comment: finally I used a curl script to do it: `while ! curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:8080; do sleep 1 && echo -n .; done;`

Comment: As a suggestion, you can also decrease the connection timeout in the netcat command to get a more quick response when Jenkins becomes up. It is, `nc -G 1 -z localhost 8000`.

Comment: nc: invalid option -- 'z'

Comment: if you use man, you'll see that it is not invalid option: "     -z      Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons, without
             sending any data to them.  It is an error to use this option in
             conjunction with the -l option.

"

Comment: In the repository version of netcat on CentOS 7, the -z option is not there. I think this is true for Fedora as well. I needed to install netcat from source to get the -z option.

Comment: This is great! Works well as a one-liner in Alpine Linux: `while ! nc -z localhost 8080; do  sleep 0.1; done`

Comment: how do i change this to wait for 2 ports to open ?

Comment: @RarylsonFreitas Do you mind linking there this `nc -G` option is documented to control timeouts? All netcat documentation I can find mentions `-G` as having to do with source routing, if the version of netcat supports `-G` at all.

Answer (score 79):

I suggest the following one liners:

```
## netcat version:
timeout 22 sh -c 'until nc -z $0 $1; do sleep 1; done' stackoverflow.com 443

## pure bash version:
timeout 22 bash -c 'until printf "" 2>>/dev/null >>/dev/tcp/$0/$1; do sleep 1; done' stackoverflow.com 443
```

Both commands exit as soon as connection is established, trying every second for up to 22 seconds.

Note that thanks to `timeout` command exit code is `0` when port is accessible otherwise `124` (if no connection established within given time).

Comment: The pure bash version is great! Can used many scenarios. Thank you!

Comment: `>>` is safer as it does not create a new file or overwrite an existing one.

Answer (score 18):

As suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149053/29674), you could also do the following if you don't have `nc` installed but just `bash` and `coreutils`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Waiting jenkins to launch on 8080..."

while ! timeout 1 bash -c "echo > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080"; do   
  sleep 1
done

echo "Jenkins launched"
```

Comment: I wonder, did `echo > ...` ever block? Under which circumstances?

Answer (score 12):

I have found this a common enough problem to write a utility to wait for a port to open, with an optional timeout:

```
# without timeout
wait-port localhost:8080

# timeout after a minute
wait-port -t 60000 localhost:8080
```

It's open source and available at [github.com/dwmkerr/wait-port](https://github.com/dwmkerr/wait-port). Hopefully others will find it useful!

Answer (score 11):

To expand on user987339's answer, here's how to easily wait for a port in your terminal:

## waitport function

Add this function to your ~/.bashrc setup file:

```
waitport() {
    while ! nc -z localhost $1 ; do sleep 1 ; done
}
```

Log out then back in to load ~/.bashrc.  Then, run this command to verify that port 3000 has a server listening to it:

```
$ waitport 3000
Connection to localhost port 3000 [tcp/hbci] succeeded!
```

This has been validated on macOS. It might not work on Fedora/CentOS, as they lack the `-z` option for `netcat`.

Answer (score 5):

I used this to wait for a couple of ports to be open, without netcat:

```
while (! (: </dev/tcp/localhost/27017) &> /dev/null || ! (: </dev/tcp/localhost/9200) &> /dev/null); do
    sleep 2;
done
```

Change `localhost` and the ports as needed.

Answer (score 4):

I use this script to check the port before running tests on CI.

```
#!/bin/bash

for _ in `seq 1 20`; do
    echo -n .
    if nc -z localhost $1; then
        exit 0
    fi
    sleep 0.5
done

exit 1
```

```
$ bin/wait-port 3306
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my one-line Bash solution (with netcat) that waits for 10 sec for a TCP connection, and give you feedback whether succeeded or not and while is waiting, and return an exit `0` code if the port is open, otherwise `1`:

```sh
bash -c 'echo -n "Waiting port 8080 .."; for _ in `seq 1 40`; do echo -n .; sleep 0.25; nc -z localhost 8080 && echo " Open." && exit ; done; echo " Timeout!" >&2; exit 1'
```

You can replace the hardcoded port `8080` by `$1` and remove the `bash -c` if the snippet is saved in a script file `wait-port` than then is called within a console with: `wait-port 8080`.

This is a recording of 3 terminals, two waiting until a port is opened and the other terminals open one of the port, so while one of the wait succeed, the other timed-out:

[image: wait-port test]

Although the line has many instructions not one, it may be useful if you need to execute the wait "remotely" in a host where you cannot store the script first, e.g. in a Docker container.

Answer (score 3):

To add onto the excellent answers above, if this is something used very often it may be worthwhile to use tooling for that purpose. I wrote and use [uup](https://github.com/jackdcasey/uup) all the time for this use case.

In your example, the command to run would be:

```
uup localhost:8080 -r
```

providing an output like:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have written a utility to wait for a port to open, it can also check MySQL, PostgreSQL, Redis and etc availability.

```
# Checking TCP port
wait4x tcp localhost:8080

# Checking TCP port with specific timeout (5 Minutes)
wait4x tcp localhost:8080 -t 5m
```

It's open source and available at https://github.com/atkrad/wait4x. Hopefully others will find it useful!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a for-loop example that has a timeout, so it tries e.g. for 10 times, with exponential backoff (2,4,8,16 seconds etc), but finally gives up. Netcat has also 1 second timeout.

```
for EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF in {1..10}; do
    nc -w 1 -z db.local 3306 && break;
    DELAY=$((2**$EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF))
    echo "db not yet available, sleeping for $DELAY seconds"
    sleep $DELAY
done
```

The output is:

```
db not yet available, sleeping for 2 seconds
db not yet available, sleeping for 4 seconds
db not yet available, sleeping for 8 seconds
db not yet available, sleeping for 16 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

**For those people who are having trouble with `nc: invalid option -- 'z'`**

I was trying to set this up in a docker image. Surprisingly, there was no option of `-z` in `nc` in that image.

Image was - `Linux elasticsearch 4.4.0-101-generic #124~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 19:05:36 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I used the following loop to wait until the port was opened.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Waiting elastic search to launch on 9200..."

open=0;
while [ $open -eq 0 ]
do
    check_port=`nc -v -w 1 -i 1 127.0.0.1 9200 &> /dev/stdout`
    echo $check_port
    if [[ "$check_port" == *"Connected to"* ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done

echo "Elastic Search launched"
```

Following is the one-liner of the above script:

```
open=0;while [ $open -eq 0 ]; do check_port=`nc -v -w 1 -i 1 127.0.0.1 9200 &> /dev/stdout`; echo $check_port; if [[ "$check_port" == *"Connected to"* ]]; then   break; fi; sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this sample usage

`./xl_wait_port.sh [port] [ up | down ]`

Parameters:

- The port to wait
- What to wait, the up or down

Which is available for download from github [xl_wait_port](https://github.com/extremelogic-ph/xl_scripts/blob/master/xl_wait_port.sh). I am the author.

Code snippet

```
echo Waiting for port $PORT_NO to go $MODE.
LOOP_FLAG=1
WARN_FLAG=1
while [ "$LOOP_FLAG" -gt 0 ]; do
  LOOP_FLAG=1
  STATUS=`lsof -i :$PORT_NO`
  if [ "up" == $MODE ]; then
    if [ "1" -eq "$STATUS" ]; then
      LOOP_FLAG=0
    fi
  else
    if [ "0" = "$STATUS" ]; then
      LOOP_FLAG=0
    fi
  fi
  RESULT=$((WARN_FLAG % 35))
  if [ "$RESULT" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "Process is taking some time. Please check or wait."
  fi
  sleep 1
  ((WARN_FLAG++))
done
echo Port $PORT_NO is now $MODE.
```