# Server notification on netcat port listen

Tags: bash, api, server, port, netcat

ServerOS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64
 
Service: Digital Ocean

I was curious if there was a way to send a notification either through an api or other method when there is activity on a server port that is open.

Situation:
I have a computer that talks to a server over a port and I can see if the computer is connected to the port using...

```
nc -l [port number]
```

but i don't want to sit there and wait for a connection, so I was interested to know if there is a way to notify when there is movement on the port using an api or bash script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait for an open port with netcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599839/how-to-wait-for-an-open-port-with-netcat)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is about waiting for the server to start listening, while this question is about waiting for a client to connect to the open port.