# Github Action: How to ensure that server is running properly?

Tags: github, concurrency, github-actions

in my GitHub action yaml file, I have two commands at the end. The first one is `yarn start` (which starts the server) and the second one is for running a test file.

from my local server I usually run `yarn start`, then wait until frontend and backend port to be run, then only I run the test from another terminal

but from GitHub action, it runs the `yarn start` command then immediately runs the test script, so when the test file is run, server is not listening on port. thats why my test scripts are failed. how can I ensure that the test script will run after the `yarn start` is finished?

here is my `action.yml` file

```
name: "Github Actions Test"
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - wip/checkout2

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      PRISMA_ENDPOINT: ${{secrets.PRISMA_ENDPOINT}}
      PRISMA_SECRET: ${{secrets.PRISMA_SECRET}}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: "Install Node"
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "12.x"
      - name: "Install global packages"
        run: npm install -g yarn prisma-cli concurrently mocha
      - name: "Run docker Container"
        run: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -d
      - name: "Install deps"
        run: yarn install
      - name: "prisma deploy"
        run: yarn deploy:backend
      - name: "Seed Backend"
        run: yarn seed:backend
      - name: "Build app"
        run: yarn build
      - name: "Start backend and frontend concurrently on background and run tests"
        run: |
          yarn start &
          yarn test
```

Comment: You're missing an extra ampersand from `yarn start`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [wait-on](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on)

```
./node_modules/.bin/wait-on tcp:3000
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do one of these:

Option 1: Wait for a few seconds before running tests:

```
run: |
  yarn start &
  sleep 10
  yarn test
```

Option 2: Wait for the port to be open with some utility designed for this purpose. Maybe [wait-port](https://dwmkerr.com/a-utility-to-help-you-wait-for-ports-to-open/) (untested)

Option 3: Wait for the port to be open using native linux tools - [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599839/how-to-wait-for-an-open-port-with-netcat), [example 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/how-do-i-tell-a-script-to-wait-for-a-process-to-start-accepting-requests-on-a-po).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what @DannyB is suggesting, you could test the server is running properly in the background by waiting some seconds and then using `curl` to test network connectivity.

For example:

```
- name: "Start backend and frontend concurrently on background and run tests"
  run: |
    yarn start &
    sleep 10 &&
    curl http://localhost:8000 &&
    yarn test
```

This way you can check the workflow job's log and confirm the server was up and running before executing tests.

If the connection is established, `curl http://localhost:<PORT>` will return the content of the web page by default. You can also add a `-I` at the end of the command to make sure to return only the request header and check if it has a `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` status.

Comment: The & - Will run ain background. What && mean?

Comment: @Misha, this stackoverflow question has some really great answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command