# Running server and dependent unit tests connection issues

Tags: github-actions, .net-4.8, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am trying to run some xunit tests which require a server that is running. I have seen some posts similar to this. I am trying something like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078178/github-action-how-to-ensure-that-server-is-running-properly), but can't get it to work.

I also went to the "Advance Settings" under "Firewall and Network Security" and added port 3333 to allow connection for the inbound and out bound ports. No matter what, when I run the unit tests after running the server, I get error saying.

```
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333.
```

The action goes into an endless loop after the error until I cancel the workflow.

Here is my entire workflow file. But please see the last step to run the CoreServer.exe in background and run the FluidtransferTests.

```yaml
name: Test unit tests CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "dev" ]

  
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-2022

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: setup Msbuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.3.1

    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.2.0

    - name: Setup VSTest Console
      uses: darenm/Setup-VSTest@v1.2


#Restore NuGet packages for CoreServer and build the Solution.

    - name: Restore NuGet packages for CoreServer
      run: nuget restore ./Core/CoreServer/CoreServer.sln

    - name: Build the CoreServer solution
      run: msbuild ./Core/CoreServer/CoreServer.sln /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release"
      

#Restore NuGet packages for CoreClient and build the Solution.

    - name: Restore NuGet packages for CoreClient
      run: nuget restore ./Core/CoreServer/CoreClient.sln

    - name: Build the CoreClient solution
      run: msbuild ./Core/CoreServer/CoreClient.sln /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release"


#Restore NuGet packages for EchoNETServer and build the Solution.

    - name: Restore NuGet packages for EchoNETServer
      run: nuget restore ./EchoNET/EchoNETServer.sln

    - name: Build the EchoNETServer solution
      run: msbuild ./EchoNET/EchoNETServer.sln /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release"


#Restore NuGet packages for EchoNETClient and build the Solution.
    
    - name: Restore NuGet packages for EchoNETClient
      run: nuget restore ./EchoNET/EchoNETClient.sln

    - name: Build the EchoNETClient solution
      run: msbuild ./EchoNET/EchoNETClient.sln /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release"


#Restore NuGet packages for EchoServer and build the Solution.
    
    - name: Restore NuGet packages for EchoServer
      run: nuget restore ./Echo/EchoServer.sln

    - name: Build the EchoServer solution
      run: msbuild ./Echo/EchoServer.sln /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release"

#Wait for the actions to complete before startinhg

    - name: Delay for the process to complete
      run: sleep 7
      

#Start CoreServer.exe in background and run the FluidtransferTests
    
    - name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background and run the FluidTransferTests
      run: |
         ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s &
         vstest.console.exe ./Pico/Medman/FluidTransferTests/bin/Release/net481/FluidTransferTests.dll
```

Upon running this, it shows the following output.

```
Run ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s &

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Microsoft.PowerShell.Man…
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.7.2 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.5+1caef2f33e (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.49]   Discovering: FluidTransferTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.42]   Discovered:  FluidTransferTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.45]   Starting:    FluidTransferTests
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect to command client exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Connect Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3333
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

EDIT:

So in the run step, I tried something like this,

```
 - name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background and run the FluidTransferTests
      run: |
         ./Core/CoreServer/Server/CoreServer/Bin/Debug/CoreServer.exe -c -s &
         curl http://localhost:3333 -I
         vstest.console.exe ./Pico/Medman/FluidTransferTests/bin/Release/net481/FluidTransferTests.dll
```

Upon running this, I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3333 after 2225 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

When I run the CoreServer and the netstat -a on my local it says it is listening on ports 3333. Please see this screenshot.

[image: ports used]

Comment: Have you verified that your server actually starts listening on port 3333 e.g. using `netcat`, `telnet`, etc.?

Comment: @Azeem I think that's the problem, can you see my edit. I was told the Server listens on ports 3333 but I can't connect to that. 
Sure let me verify if the Server actually listens on the port 3333.

Comment: @Azeem may be let me start the CoreServer.exe using GitHub actions. And then I'll open the windows command prompt and run netstat -a

Comment: Run `netstat -ntp` after starting the server in GHA workflow.

Comment: In your logs, port 3338 is also there for SSL. Could that be the correct port? Please verify that as well.

Comment: @Azeem I tried netstat -ntp after running the server, it displays Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           Offload State. Is the Server being stopped right after it runs? Or is it because I am running the job as a background task its not displaying anything

Comment: So, the server is no longer running. Have you tested the same scenario on your local machine? Does it work there? Have you tried other variants running a program in the background?

Comment: @Azeem In the edit the screenshot that I have is when I was running on my local. When I say CoreServer.exe -c -s it runs fine on the local as in the sceenshots. On GHA if I run on foreground, the server throws an error because its a blocking call waiting for an input from user to stop after start. If you don't specify any input, the server will keep running as is. So I am trying to run in the background.

Comment: @Azeem is there a way to open the background tasks to see the output of it in GHA. Because when I run the server, it prints the output to the Console saying its running on so and so port etc, like in the screenshot in the post.

Comment: The default shell on your Windows GHA-hosted runner is Powershell so you can look it up how you can redirect its STDOUT and/or STDERR. In your screenshot, you're using Command Prompt and not Powershell. You should use the same shell locally and on the GHA runner. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell for more details on shells.

Comment: Hi @Azeem I have created a public repository with the Server files that contains the .exe and dlls. I also created a small workflow to run the Server. Can you please look at this https://github.com/ussainik45/Server

Comment: @Azeem Thanks for the info about the runners I will use cmd shell for my workflow.

Comment: Hi @Azeem its a post you suggested to try. Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77316114/running-a-server-in-background-using-cmd-shell-for-windows

Comment: Sure, I'll check that repo later and update here. Looks like you're still stuck with that [earlier issue](https://github.com/ussainik45/Server/actions/runs/6560766400/job/17819085607#step:4:31). Please make it work under Powershell as it was fixed in that. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem Thank you. Yes I am still struck with the old issue. I asked this question how to run it using cmd shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77316114/running-a-server-in-background-using-cmd-shell-for-windows. It works but it doesn't start the action in background.

Comment: Running it doesn't work because it exits due to this exception `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Labcyte.Core.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\nandukurusai\Desktop\GITSourceCode\Echo65XPlus\Core\CoreServer\Server\CoreServer\Program.cs:line 203`. Run command: `Start-Process -NoNewWindow powershell { .\Debug\CoreServer.exe -c -s }`

Comment: Check its test [run](https://github.com/iamazeem/Server/actions/runs/6562448576/job/17824406081) and [workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/Server/actions/runs/6562448576/workflow). Your devs might have better idea why this is happening. Adding exception handling might be helpful.

Comment: @Azeem Thank you so much I will reach out. What is happening is, once the server starts, its waiting for an input from the user to enter something to stop the server. If you don't press anything, the server just runs. But in case of GH actions, its not liking the blocking call.

Comment: @Azeem can you please help me with the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77329442/github-actions-not-running-in-background-when-shell-is-cmd The server is working now without error

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look at your latest build and update you later.

Comment: @Azeem Can you start the server in the background and run the FluidTransferTests.dll that's what I am trying to do

Comment: @Azeem Thank you I got it to work... Start-Process C:\PROJBACKUP\Echo65XPlus\Core\CoreServer\Server\CoreServer\bin\Debug\CoreServer.exe -ArgumentList "-c -s" -NoNewWindow & runs in background and the unittests are working :)