# GitHub actions not running in background when shell is cmd

Tags: github-actions, background-process, cicd

I have a scenario where in, I want to run the server in the background and run the unit tests that are dependent on the server. Problem is, if I remove `shell=cmd` and run, it runs fine in background but uses Windows Powershell as the default shell. In this case it clearly shows, running as background task.

But I don't want that. I want the shell to be cmd. When I specify `shell=cmd`, the server operation just blocks.

I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/ussainik45/Server).

These are my entire actions:

```
name: Test unit tests CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]


jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-2022

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: setup Msbuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.3.1

    - name: Setup VSTest Console
      uses: darenm/Setup-VSTest@v1.2


#try nc -v -N 127.0.0.1 3334
 #curl http://localhost:3333 -I
 #vstest.console.exe ./Pico/Medman/FluidTransferTests/bin/Release/net481/FluidTransferTests.dll
#Start CoreServer.exe in background

    - name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background
      shell: cmd
      run: |
         echo git | .\Debug\CoreServer.exe -c -s &
         vstest.console.exe .\Tests\FluidTransferTests.dll
```

You see it just keeps spinning shows "waiting for SSL client" and doesn't proceed further to execute the tests.

[image: Server blocked]

### Edit

As per the suggestion, in my run step I tried the following but still won't help still gives the same output.

```
- name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background
      shell: cmd
      run: |
         start /b echo git | .\Debug\CoreServer.exe -c -s
         vstest.console.exe .\Tests\FluidTransferTests.dll
```

Also tried, and still the same.

```
- name: Start CoreServer.exe in the background
      shell: cmd
      run: |
         start /B echo git | .\Debug\CoreServer.exe -c -s &  start /B vstest.console.exe .\Tests\FluidTransferTests.dll
```

### Edit

I have tried many ways one of them is,

```
start /B "echo git | CoreServer.exe -c -s"
```

When I try like above it says, (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. But surely its not running the Server.

Also tried:

```
start /B "" echo git | CoreServer.exe -c -s
```

But doing so looks like its not starting the server in background.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21031259/736079

Comment: @jessehouwing I tried "start /b echo git | .\Debug\CoreServer.exe -c -s" and still the same :(

Comment: @jessehouwing please see my edits

Comment: Of course, cause that will start the "echo" in the background. Why no try these things in your own local shell first to get to a syntax that works.

Comment: @jessehouwing sure thanks I will

Comment: @jessehouwing Can you see my last edit. I really can't get it to work running it in background. Can you please help with the right command...

Comment: simplest solution is to probably put your startup command in a `.cmd` file and call that using `start /b` doing input/output redirection while launching into the background is a bit hard to get right.

Comment: @jessehouwing  Powershell looks like its easier because it works with just an & looks like. I am trying start-process "CoreServer.exe" -argumentlist '-c','-s' & but it gives me an error. Is it easier on Powershell? I know in the post I said I don't want poweshell. But at this point, I don't care. Want to run the Server in background

Comment: I did not downvote. But if you're open to feedback, you've presented this as a GitHub-actions problem, where it's a Windows Shell issue. In that case you'd be better off on superuser.com to get your answers. And you've ignored previous advice in other Qs not to use a construct like this, because it's not how GitHub Action wis designed to work. I get that it might be frustrating, but execution in GitHub Actions is linear and doesn't run things in parallel. Github Actions cleans up after itself.

Comment: Better way is to make "Start CoreServer.exe in the background" as a separate step inside the same job (that can use PowerShell as the shell) and another job which runs unit tests which is dependent on previous job which runs on cmd shell