# How to debug Node.js child process EBADF errors

Tags: node.js, posix, gnu, child-process

I have a Node.js development environment process manager that consistently after ~20 minutes of work starts throwing a `spawn EBADF` error (see truncated stack below) every time I try to spawn a new process.

```
Error: spawn EBADF
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:420:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
    at [...] {
  errno: -9,
  code: 'EBADF',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
```

I've logged the stats object for the executable I'm trying to spawn when the error is thrown:

```
Stats {
  dev: 16777233,
  mode: 33261,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 25264887,
  size: 5336594,
  blocks: 10424,
  atimeMs: 1697802509011.12,
  mtimeMs: 1668201906279.7305,
  ctimeMs: 1668201906279.7305,
  birthtimeMs: 1668201906249.335,
  atime: 2023-10-20T11:48:29.011Z,
  mtime: 2022-11-11T21:25:06.280Z,
  ctime: 2022-11-11T21:25:06.280Z,
  birthtime: 2022-11-11T21:25:06.249Z
}
```

The `mode` implies the file is executable. I expect the error is somewhere in my environment but I don't know how to continue debugging. What's the next step for debugging Node.js internals? How can I see the specific spawn call it's making to try and detect where the error is coming from? Are there any other files that participate in a Node.js spawn I should be checking to make sure are still good?

Comment: An `EBADF` error generally is a bad file descriptor. This might be an issue with the file I/O at the system level rather than a simple issue with your Node.js. What is the output of `ulimit -n` on your machine?

Comment: To answer your question plainly though, you can use this format `NODE_DEBUG=child_process node yourscript.js` for internal details about spawn calls and related operations. But I'm not sure how much this will help. If it doesn't help you figure out the issue, let me know, and we can just monitor the number of file descriptors on your node process as it runs.

Comment: The output of `ulimit -n` on my machine is 256. I'll try running with `NODE_DEBUG=child_process` and report back! Thanks for introducing that env variable

Comment: How would I monitor the number of file descriptors from my process?

Comment: Got my first EBADF error today. It was after 168 `CHILD_PROCESS` logs from Node.js. Restarting the process fixes it. I took the file path from the debug logs and confirmed the file exists and is executable.

Comment: In trying to debug this, I’ve looked a little bit at libuv’s process spawning code. I don’t have full context on process spawning at the POSIX level but saw there was some forking of the current process involved. I wonder if my build system is touching the executable that’s running in some bad way and that’s causing an issue?

Comment: You may already know this but on Linux open file descriptors can be tracked under `/proc/[processid]/fd/`.

Comment: I did not know this! I’m on MacOS, though, looks like the equivalent command is `lsof -p PID`. Running that I have 10k+ entries! Only ~9 file descriptors then 10k+ IPv4 ports. (Whenever a process restarts, I pick a new port.)

Comment: Here’s an example of one entry from that output: `node, 95557, calebmer, 3533u, IPv4, 0x152a14f534986c15, 0t0, TCP, localhost:52266->localhost:52034 (CLOSED)`. I’m using the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-port to find unused ports. Is there anything else I need to do to free a port (other than shutting down the server listening on it)? Could that be related?

Comment: @WeijunZhou That is actually a new one for me and extremely helpful. Thank you 

Comment: _(previously deleted to remove grammar mistakes)_ Nice work debugging this, and you are right on the money using `lsof -p PID`. Your user limit (the output of `ulimit -n`) seems incredibly low to my knowledge. For example, my machine is currently at `12800` (this was my default value), but I think you would only need around `4096`. Can you do a temporary increase by running `ulimit -n 4096` and let me know the output?

Comment: One thing that is very odd is that the output you shared about the entries suggests that ports are being opened but not properly closed. I am guessing every time a process restarts, a new port is picked, which could be causing an accumulation of used ports. After running each of these tests have you happened to confirm that the ports are being properly released (using `lsof -i` for example)?

Comment: Actually, I think `lsof` is outputting TCP connections that haven’t been released. (Instead of a port I’m not properly closing.) To confirm this, after restarting my process I see in a memory snapshot from the Chrome inspector ~500 TCP objects and ~500 `lsof` TCP entries. What’s strange is for most of the TCP objects in the snapshot it reports the only retainers as “Node / CleanupQueue” and “(Global handles)” (forcing GC doesn’t seem to clean, neither does waiting ~5min)

Comment: I’ll try raising my `ulimit`! Regardless it seems like I have some kind of leak. I’m now having trouble finding the source of that leak though…

Comment: Weird that snapshot indicates the connections are waiting to be cleaned up but aren't being released effectively. I wonder if GC not getting around to cleaning them, or if there might be some references preventing their release. Is this code publicly available?

Comment: It is not, but I’m nearing a minimal reproduction. When my processes start up, I have a `while` loop making a network request waiting for their port to be available. The number of attempted connections with `ECONNREFUSED` is directly matching the number of open TCP connections.

Comment: This script reproduces my file descriptor leak: https://gist.github.com/calebmer/b3e648dc650a0a68f89aa00ae4af8891. Run `lsof -p $PID` on this process and see how it keeps going up

Comment: Maybe premature but this is feeling like a Node.js bug so I filed an issue there: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/50479

Comment: I replaced my Node.js function that checks if a port is available with a small bash script based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599839/how-to-wait-for-an-open-port-with-netcat. Now it looks like the file descriptor leak is gone. Let’s hope my EBADF errors are gone too! Won't find that out until after a day of normal development…

Comment: I haven’t gotten an EBADF error after a day of development! @PCDSandwichMan if you want to leave an answer saying this is caused when you run out of file descriptors, happy to accept the answer and give it the bounty.